# How to limit the count of rows for a specific foreign key value in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

We have a posts table and user_id is the foreign key
For example, I want to choose posts for these users

```
$users=[1,2,13,16,17,19];
$posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $users)->paginate(10);
```

But I want the user 1 and 2 only have two posts in the output, for the rest of the users there is not a limited number of posts.

> Note: User 1 and 2 are not always within the `$users` array, and due to the condition, one or both of them may not be in the array.

Do you have a solution for me?

Comment: User 1 and User 2 both will have 2 posts each or they will have two posts combined?

Comment: Is it always 1 and 2 which must be limited to two posts?   and which two post the first two post or the last two posts?

Comment: @Mozammil User 1 Two posts and user 2 Two posts in total 4 posts

Comment: @Rehan Yes, it's always 1 and 2, and the two last posts of these users must be selected

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code.  [SO is not a code-writing service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348591/how-to-flag-close-as-not-a-code-writing-service).

Comment: @Don'tPanic I wanted to use the union, but since it was used for another result, I'm trying to find a better solution

Comment: Show us your code.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks, I will check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this alternative :

```
$posts = [];
$users=[1,2,13,16,17,19];
$userWithJustTwo = [1,2];
$result = array_intersect($users, $userWithJustTwo); 
$posts[] = Post::whereIn('user_id', $result)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(2)->get();
$array = array_diff($users, userWithJustTwo);
$posts[] = Post::whereIn('user_id', $array)->get();
```

Comment: This we not get the last two post as OP asked for user [1,2]

Comment: @Maraboc Thanks, let me check this

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve  this in a single query, we need to take it separately like this

```
$users=[1,2,13,16,17,19];
// first take all the post except the two
$posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $users)->whereNotIn('user_id', [1,2])->get()->toArray();
// then take one user 1 post in desc and limit it by 2
$userOnePost = Post::whereIn('user_id', $users)->where('user_id', 1)->limit(2)->orderBy('post.id', 'desc')->get()->toArray();
// then take one user 2 post in desc and limit it by 2
$userTwoPost = Post::whereIn('user_id', $users)->where('user_id', 2)->limit(2)->orderBy('post.id', 'desc')->get()->toArray();

// merge all the array
$allPost = array_merge(posts,$userOnePost,userTwoPost);
```

Comment: Check this and let me know whether it was useful @Vajiheh habibi

Comment: Thanks, let me check this

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `->take()`

```
$posts = [];
$users=[1,2,13,16,17,19];

foreach($users as $user)
{
    if($user == 1 || $user == 2)
    {
        $posts[] = Post::where('user_id', $user)->take(2)->get();
    }
    else
    {
       $posts[] = Post::where('user_id', $user)->get();
    }
}
```

Read more at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

Comment: Is it not recommended to run queries inside a loop. It must be avoided at all cost.

Comment: In this answer, you can filter how many post you want to get for the `user 1` and `user 2` by using the `->take()` and the rest will take all the post.

Comment: @Rehan, O I see? but may I ask why?

Comment: Even if it takes, queries are running in a loop which must be avoided.

Comment: If suppose, you have 100K rows, the queries must run 100k times and effects the performance of the application,

Comment: It is recommended to fetch the data in a single query and then alter it using loop.

Comment: Check my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this method:

```
$users = User::whereNotIn('id', [1,2])->pluck('id');
$posts = [];

$posts[] = Post::whereIn('user_id', [1,2])->take(2)->get();
$posts[] = Post::whereIn('user_id', $users)->get();
```

if you want to get the latest `post` use this instead:

```
$posts[] = Post::whereIn('user_id', [1,2])->latest('created_at')->take(2)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you may also use Parameter Grouping like this

```
DB::table('post')
            ->whereIn('user_id', $users)
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->whereIn('user_id', [1,2])->limit(2)
                      ->orWhereNotIn('user_id', [1,2]);
            })
            ->get();
```